# Points on ellipsoid with maximum Gaussian curvature/mean curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, ellipsoids

> Find the points on the ellipsoid $$x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$$ with maximum Gaussian curvature and mean curvature respectively.

I parametrized it as $(a\sin u\cos v,b\sin u\sin v, c\cos v)$ and managed to compute its Guassian and mean curvature, which are both very messy:$$
K(u,v)=\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{[a^2b^2\cos^2v+c^2(b^2\cos^2u+a^2\sin^2u)\sin^2v]^2 } 
$$
and 
$$H(u,v) =\frac{abc[3(a^2+b^2)+2c^2+(a^2+b^2-2c^2)\cos(2v)-2(a^2-b^2)\cos(2u)\sin^2v]}{8[a^2b^2\cos^2v+c^2(b^2\cos^2u+a^2\sin^2u)\sin^2v]^{3/2}}$$

How can I cleverly find points which maximize the complicated $K$ or $H$? (Perhaps in less than 2 pages of computation, by some geometric reasoning?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gaussian and mean curvatures](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540710/gaussian-and-mean-curvatures)

Comment: at least for finding the minimum and maximum of the Gauss curvature it is not necessary to actually compute it, if you know the geometric meaning. The points where the biggest inscribed and smallest enclosing spheres meet the ellipsoid are good candidates to start the search.

Comment: Surely for the ellipsoid the maximum Gaussian and mean curvatures both occur at the extreme points, i.e. if $a<\min(b,c)$ then $(\pm1/a,0,0)$, and so on. I don't have a proof, but isn't there a way to compute curvatures directly from the $f(x,y,z)=0$ form of the surface?

Comment: @HansEngler For me it is sad to see that people on this site by now seem to invest more work in finding "potential duplicates" (and pointing to questions which actually are no duplicates), instead of noting that something else was actually asked and then trying to find a better solution for the problem at hand. Mathematics, for me, is not about pointing to some (too complicated) solution which, by accident, might provide an answer to the current question, but about taking the problem at hand seriously and thinking of a possibly easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known extreme curvatures occur at ends of major/minor axes for each of $ xy,yz,zx $ sections.This fact should be used to evaluate only at the 6 principal points.

Differentiating $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ twice, curvature at end of minor axis = $ b/a^2 $. In the perpendicular direction $ b/c^2$ by symmetry.

Product: Gaussian curvatures $ (b/ac)^2 $ and two other cyclic symmetry curvatures.

Similarly,

Half-sum: Mean curvatures $ \dfrac {b(a^2 +c^2)}{2 a^2 c^2 } $   and two cyclic symmetry curvatures.

Depending upon relative magnitudes of $a,b,c$ maximum curvatures can be selected.

EDIT1:

Although it is known that maximum curvatures occur at ends of major/minor axes due to two-fold symmetry of coordinate axes, it can be shown by differential calculus method for natural equations of conics (1) , (2) below established by me earlier as properties of conics. Looks tedious for what is obvious.

*Notation:*

Slope of tangent to x-axis $= \phi$, angle between radius vector and ellipse in Newton eccentric focus polar coordinate  model $\epsilon= $ eccentricity, $p$ semi-latus rectum. Now,

$$ \frac{\cos \psi}{ \cos \phi}= \epsilon \tag{1}$$
$$ p k_g = \sin ^{3}\psi \tag{2}$$
Differentiating (2)with respect to elliptic arc $s$
$$p k_g^{'} =  3 \sin ^{2}\psi \cos \psi  \psi^{'} \tag{3}$$

Liouville's formula for curvature polar coordinates

$$ k_g = \psi^{'} + \frac{\sin \psi}{r} \tag{4} $$

From (3) and (4)
$$ p k_g^{'} = 3 \sin \psi ^{3} \cos \psi \left( \frac{\sin ^{2}\psi }{p} -\frac{1}{r}  \right) \tag {5} $$

Multiply by $p$ both sides

$$ p^2 k_g^{'} = 3 \sin \psi ^{3} \cos \psi \left( \sin ^2\psi  - p/r\right ) \tag{6} $$

$ \psi = \pi/2$ at ends of major axes,$ \, \because  $  coefficient and  derivative vanish curvature is a maximum.

Newton's canonical ellipse equation

$$ \frac{p}{r} = 1 - \epsilon \cos \theta \tag {7} $$

The quantity in brackets of (6) becomes

$$ -( \epsilon \cos \theta - \cos^2\psi )\tag{8} $$

The situation at ends of minor axis can now be tackled:

$$ \phi = 0, \theta = \psi \tag{9} $$

Quantity in brackets

$$ -\cos \psi ( \epsilon -\cos \psi) \tag {11}$$

From (1) at $\phi =0 , \epsilon = \cos \psi \tag{12}$

From (11) and (12)  the derivative vanishes at $y=b$ also, curvature here also is an extremum.

The logic holds for other two $ yz, zx $ plane sections as well.

Sign of next derivative for max/min of curvature can be verified by reader :).

EDIT2:

By virtue of pairwise application Euler's theorem for normal curvature

$$ \kappa_{n1,2}= \kappa_1 \cos^2 \psi_{12} + \kappa_2 \sin^2 \psi_{12} ;\ \kappa_{n1,3}= \kappa_1 \cos^2 \psi_{13} + \kappa_3 \sin^2 \psi_{13}$$

the lines of principal curvature ( simply called curvature in differential geometry) have extrema combinations at these six " cardinal" points.

As far as I am concerned it is demonstrated.

EDIT3

Having said that there a much simpler way to show it. The necessary and sufficient requirement for maximization is $ \dfrac{d \,\kappa_n}{d \psi} = 0 $ and for $ \kappa_{n}= \kappa_1 \cos^2 \psi + \kappa_2 \sin^2 \psi $ the derivative is:

$$\frac{d\, \kappa_n}{d \psi} = -2 (\kappa_1 -\kappa_2 )\cos \psi \sin \psi $$

This is (twice negative) *geodesic torsion $\tau_g $* that should vanish at all the 6 points ( $\psi =\pi/2 $ ) at ends of major and minor axes. As usual Mohr's circle of curvature depicts these nicely.

Comment: Would you mind explaining hoe to show that extreme curvatures occurs at the end of axes?

Comment: EDIT1 as required.

Comment: It seems to me that, you have proven for any ellipse, the 4 extreme points has maximal and minimal curvature. But this is seems not enough to conclude that the maximal and minimal prinical curvature on ellipsoid occurs at the 6 extreme points.

Comment: EDIT2: as required.

Answer (score 2):

Using the implicit definition of this surface may be a better approach. Let $$F(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} - 1.$$ The ellipsoid is then defined by $F(x,y,z) = 0$. Then it is [known](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.413.3008&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that the Gaussian curvature at a point $(x,y,z)$ is given by
$$\kappa = \frac{g H^{ad}g^T}{|g|^4}.$$
and the mean curvature is given by
$$h = \frac{gHg^T - \operatorname{trace}(H)|g|^2}{2|g|^3}.$$
where $g = \nabla F$ is the gradient, $H = \nabla g$ is the Hessian matrix, and $H^{ad}$ is its adjoint. Here
$$
g = (2x/a^2, 2y/b^2, 2z/c^2), \, H = \begin{pmatrix} 2/a^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2/b^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2/c^2 \end{pmatrix} , \quad
H^{ad} = \begin{pmatrix}4/(b^2c^2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4/(a^2c^2) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4/(a^2b^2) \end{pmatrix} 
$$
and therefore
$$
|g|^4 = 16\left( (x^2/a^4 + y^2/b^4 + z^2/c^4) \right)^2, \quad
gH^{ad} g^T = 16\frac{x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2}{a^2b^2c^2} = \frac{16}{a^2b^2c^2}  \, .
$$

The Guassian curvature can now be maximized as follows. We obtain
$$
\kappa = \frac{1}{a^2b^2c^2\left( (x^2/a^4 + y^2/b^4 + z^2/c^4) \right)^2} \, .
$$
Now it is enough to find the extrema of the denominator, subject to the constraint $F(x,y,z) = 0$ which leads to the Lagrange multiplier equations
$$
2x/a^4 = 2\lambda x/a^2, \quad 2y/b^4 = 2\lambda y/b^2, \quad 2z/c^4 = 2\lambda z/c^2\, .
$$
In the generic case where $a,b,c$ are all different, this means $x(\lambda - a^2) = y(\lambda - b^2) = z(\lambda - c^2) = 0$. This is only possible if any two of the unknowns are zero and the third one isn't. Therefore the critical points of $\kappa$ on the ellipsoid are  $(\pm a,0,0), (0,\pm b, 0,0), (0,0,\pm c)$ with Gaussian curvatures $ \frac{a^2}{b^2c^2}, \frac{b^2}{a^2c^2},\frac{c^2}{a^2b^2}$. Pick the largest one and that's the maximum.

Comment: This approach to find maximum of $K$ is quite good, do you have any idea for maximizing mean curvature?

Comment: You mean the *umbilics*? $( \kappa_1=   \kappa_2) ?$ Umbilc points of the ellipsoid lie in a plane of [Max(a,b,c) and Min(a,b,c)] and have coordinates $ (a \sqrt{ \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2-c^2}}, 0, c \sqrt{ \dfrac{b^2-c^2}{a^2-c^2}}).  $

Comment: @Narasimham: I mean finding a point on the ellipsoid which maximize the mean curvature. (Though I am also curious about how to find the umbilic points)

Comment: You can use the same approach to find the extrema of the mean curvature. Set up everything in terms of $x,y,z$ and use constrained optimization. It will be a bit messier.