# What is the mean curvature of the hyper-ellipsoid $\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x^\top B x = r\}$ as a function of $r$ and the condition number of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, curvature, convex-geometry, ellipsoids

Let $B$ be an $n \times n$ positive-definite matrix and let $r>0$. Consider the hyper-ellipsoid $E_B \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ defined by

$$
E_B(r) := \left\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x^\top B x = r \right\}.
$$

The hyper-sphere of radius $r$ corresponds to $E_{I_n}(r)$, and it is known to have mean curvature $1/r^2$.

> **Question.** *What is the mean curvature of $E_B(r)$, for general $B$ ? Can the mean curvature be written as a function of only $r$ and the condition number of $B$, that is the ratio of the longest to the shortes axes of $E_B(r)$ or equivalently, the ratio of the largest to the smallest singular-values of $B$ ?*

Comment: I wasn't sure what notion of "curvature" would be appropriate here, that's why I inserted the quotation signs. I will settle for global min and max values of mean curvature. Question update.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1484420/339790)

Comment: You make it sound like the mean curvature is a constant. This is true only in the case of a sphere. It is the average of the principal curvatures and will vary in a complicated way. So I don't understand what your question can even begin to mean.